# Why can the definite integral of a function f from a to b be interpreted as the net sign area...?

Tags: definite-integrals, continuity, indefinite-integrals

between the graph of f and the interval [a,b], only if f is continuous?

This is what my textbook mean by "net sign area":
[image]

I don't think f has to continuous for this to be true. For example, f can be like this:
[image]
...and there to me is still a net sign area.

Comment: That doesn't change anything . It isn't always true if if f is not continuous hence it could not say any f

Comment: Can you pls give an example where this is not true?

Comment: The characteristic function of rationals

Comment: For functions with finitely many discontinuities (like your picture), the areas analogy still makes some sense: just consider the integral as separate integrals/areas (e.g. in your picture, three integrals/areas). However the notion of "net signed area" for arbitrary functions $f$ is not always clear (see Quality's example above).

Comment: @Quality I would still think of the integral of the characteristic function of the rationals as an area: a countable amount of line segments has the same area of a line, i.e. $0$.

Comment: @Quality, yea I can see how it doesn't work with asymptotes.